# Oil pressure light on Golf R Mark 7

Tags: oil, vw, golf, pressure

This morning my car stalled when I turned on the engine (left it in gear the night before, stupid me) and my oil pressure light came up for a few seconds then it disappeared. Will it be fine?

Comment: Assuming this is not a manual (as leaving a manual in gear is quite common AFAIK.) However, check the oil level. If normal I wouldn't worry.

Comment: It's a manual haha literally forgot to put it back to neutral.

Comment: Low RPMs are going to lead to low oil pressure.  Sounds normal.

Answer (score 2):

This site already has a few ["what gear to leave a parked manual"](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39007/whats-the-best-gear-to-leave-a-manual-vehicle-in-when-parked?noredirect=1&lq=1). Answers vary but I have found no evidence (neither on this site nor elsewhere) that parking in a low gear is actually *harmful*. Actually, that was how I learned to leave a parked car.

As for your question, I would advice that you **check the engine oil level**. If normal, nothing to worry about.